# c++ linking error : cannot link objects

Tags: c++, linker

I am trying to compile a program in c++
the headers are defined in .h and the definition is in cpp files
the problem is that i'm gotting linking error

```
layer.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall input_layer::input_layer(int,int)" (??0input_layer@@QAE@HH@Z) already defined in kohonen.obj
layer.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall input_layer::~input_layer(void)" (??1input_layer@@QAE@XZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layer.obj : error LNK2005: "public: virtual void __thiscall input_layer::calc_out(void)" (?calc_out@input_layer@@UAEXXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layer.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall output_layer::output_layer(int,int)" (??0output_layer@@QAE@HH@Z) already defined in kohonen.obj
layer.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall output_layer::~output_layer(void)" (??1output_layer@@QAE@XZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layer.obj : error LNK2005: "public: virtual void __thiscall output_layer::calc_out(void)" (?calc_out@output_layer@@UAEXXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layer.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall output_layer::calc_error(float &)" (?calc_error@output_layer@@QAEXAAM@Z) already defined in kohonen.obj
layer.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall output_layer::randomize_weights(void)" (?randomize_weights@output_layer@@QAEXXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layer.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall output_layer::update_weights(float)" (?update_weights@output_layer@@QAEXM@Z) already defined in kohonen.obj
layer.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall output_layer::list_weights(void)" (?list_weights@output_layer@@QAEXXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layer.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall output_layer::list_errors(void)" (?list_errors@output_layer@@QAEXXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layer.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall output_layer::write_weights(int,struct _iobuf *)" (?write_weights@output_layer@@QAEXHPAU_iobuf@@@Z) already defined in kohonen.obj
layer.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall output_layer::read_weights(int,struct _iobuf *)" (?read_weights@output_layer@@QAEXHPAU_iobuf@@@Z) already defined in kohonen.obj
layer.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall output_layer::list_outputs(void)" (?list_outputs@output_layer@@QAEXXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layer.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall middle_layer::middle_layer(int,int)" (??0middle_layer@@QAE@HH@Z) already defined in kohonen.obj
layer.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall middle_layer::~middle_layer(void)" (??1middle_layer@@QAE@XZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layer.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall middle_layer::calc_error(void)" (?calc_error@middle_layer@@QAEXXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layer.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall network::network(void)" (??0network@@QAE@XZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layer.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall network::~network(void)" (??1network@@QAE@XZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layer.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall network::set_training(unsigned int const &)" (?set_training@network@@QAEXABI@Z) already defined in kohonen.obj
layer.obj : error LNK2005: "public: unsigned int __thiscall network::get_training_value(void)" (?get_training_value@network@@QAEIXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layer.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall network::get_layer_info(void)" (?get_layer_info@network@@QAEXXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layer.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall network::set_up_network(void)" (?set_up_network@network@@QAEXXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layer.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall network::randomize_weights(void)" (?randomize_weights@network@@QAEXXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layer.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall network::update_weights(float)" (?update_weights@network@@QAEXM@Z) already defined in kohonen.obj
layer.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall network::write_weights(struct _iobuf *)" (?write_weights@network@@QAEXPAU_iobuf@@@Z) already defined in kohonen.obj
layer.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall network::read_weights(struct _iobuf *)" (?read_weights@network@@QAEXPAU_iobuf@@@Z) already defined in kohonen.obj
layer.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall network::list_weights(void)" (?list_weights@network@@QAEXXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layer.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall network::list_outputs(void)" (?list_outputs@network@@QAEXXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layer.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall network::write_outputs(struct _iobuf *)" (?write_outputs@network@@QAEXPAU_iobuf@@@Z) already defined in kohonen.obj
layer.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall network::list_errors(void)" (?list_errors@network@@QAEXXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layer.obj : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall network::fill_IObuffer(struct _iobuf *)" (?fill_IObuffer@network@@QAEHPAU_iobuf@@@Z) already defined in kohonen.obj
layer.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall network::set_up_pattern(int)" (?set_up_pattern@network@@QAEXH@Z) already defined in kohonen.obj
layer.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall network::forward_prop(void)" (?forward_prop@network@@QAEXXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layer.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall network::backward_prop(float &)" (?backward_prop@network@@QAEXAAM@Z) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall Kohonen_layer::Kohonen_layer(int,int,int)" (??0Kohonen_layer@@QAE@HHH@Z) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall Kohonen_layer::~Kohonen_layer(void)" (??1Kohonen_layer@@QAE@XZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: virtual void __thiscall Kohonen_layer::calc_out(void)" (?calc_out@Kohonen_layer@@UAEXXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Kohonen_layer::randomize_weights(void)" (?randomize_weights@Kohonen_layer@@QAEXXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Kohonen_layer::update_neigh_size(int)" (?update_neigh_size@Kohonen_layer@@QAEXH@Z) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Kohonen_layer::update_weights(float)" (?update_weights@Kohonen_layer@@QAEXM@Z) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Kohonen_layer::list_weights(void)" (?list_weights@Kohonen_layer@@QAEXXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Kohonen_layer::list_outputs(void)" (?list_outputs@Kohonen_layer@@QAEXXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: float __thiscall Kohonen_layer::get_win_dist(void)" (?get_win_dist@Kohonen_layer@@QAEMXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall Kohonen_network::Kohonen_network(void)" (??0Kohonen_network@@QAE@XZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall Kohonen_network::~Kohonen_network(void)" (??1Kohonen_network@@QAE@XZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Kohonen_network::get_layer_info(void)" (?get_layer_info@Kohonen_network@@QAEXXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Kohonen_network::set_up_network(int)" (?set_up_network@Kohonen_network@@QAEXH@Z) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Kohonen_network::randomize_weights(void)" (?randomize_weights@Kohonen_network@@QAEXXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Kohonen_network::update_neigh_size(int)" (?update_neigh_size@Kohonen_network@@QAEXH@Z) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Kohonen_network::update_weights(float)" (?update_weights@Kohonen_network@@QAEXM@Z) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Kohonen_network::list_weights(void)" (?list_weights@Kohonen_network@@QAEXXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Kohonen_network::list_outputs(void)" (?list_outputs@Kohonen_network@@QAEXXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Kohonen_network::get_next_vector(struct _iobuf *)" (?get_next_vector@Kohonen_network@@QAEXPAU_iobuf@@@Z) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Kohonen_network::process_next_pattern(void)" (?process_next_pattern@Kohonen_network@@QAEXXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: float __thiscall Kohonen_network::get_win_dist(void)" (?get_win_dist@Kohonen_network@@QAEMXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall Kohonen_network::get_win_index(void)" (?get_win_index@Kohonen_network@@QAEHXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall input_layer::input_layer(int,int)" (??0input_layer@@QAE@HH@Z) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall input_layer::~input_layer(void)" (??1input_layer@@QAE@XZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: virtual void __thiscall input_layer::calc_out(void)" (?calc_out@input_layer@@UAEXXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall output_layer::output_layer(int,int)" (??0output_layer@@QAE@HH@Z) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall output_layer::~output_layer(void)" (??1output_layer@@QAE@XZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: virtual void __thiscall output_layer::calc_out(void)" (?calc_out@output_layer@@UAEXXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall output_layer::calc_error(float &)" (?calc_error@output_layer@@QAEXAAM@Z) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall output_layer::randomize_weights(void)" (?randomize_weights@output_layer@@QAEXXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall output_layer::update_weights(float)" (?update_weights@output_layer@@QAEXM@Z) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall output_layer::list_weights(void)" (?list_weights@output_layer@@QAEXXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall output_layer::list_errors(void)" (?list_errors@output_layer@@QAEXXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall output_layer::write_weights(int,struct _iobuf *)" (?write_weights@output_layer@@QAEXHPAU_iobuf@@@Z) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall output_layer::read_weights(int,struct _iobuf *)" (?read_weights@output_layer@@QAEXHPAU_iobuf@@@Z) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall output_layer::list_outputs(void)" (?list_outputs@output_layer@@QAEXXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall middle_layer::middle_layer(int,int)" (??0middle_layer@@QAE@HH@Z) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall middle_layer::~middle_layer(void)" (??1middle_layer@@QAE@XZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall middle_layer::calc_error(void)" (?calc_error@middle_layer@@QAEXXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall network::network(void)" (??0network@@QAE@XZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall network::~network(void)" (??1network@@QAE@XZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall network::set_training(unsigned int const &)" (?set_training@network@@QAEXABI@Z) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: unsigned int __thiscall network::get_training_value(void)" (?get_training_value@network@@QAEIXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall network::get_layer_info(void)" (?get_layer_info@network@@QAEXXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall network::set_up_network(void)" (?set_up_network@network@@QAEXXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall network::randomize_weights(void)" (?randomize_weights@network@@QAEXXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall network::update_weights(float)" (?update_weights@network@@QAEXM@Z) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall network::write_weights(struct _iobuf *)" (?write_weights@network@@QAEXPAU_iobuf@@@Z) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall network::read_weights(struct _iobuf *)" (?read_weights@network@@QAEXPAU_iobuf@@@Z) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall network::list_weights(void)" (?list_weights@network@@QAEXXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall network::list_outputs(void)" (?list_outputs@network@@QAEXXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall network::write_outputs(struct _iobuf *)" (?write_outputs@network@@QAEXPAU_iobuf@@@Z) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall network::list_errors(void)" (?list_errors@network@@QAEXXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall network::fill_IObuffer(struct _iobuf *)" (?fill_IObuffer@network@@QAEHPAU_iobuf@@@Z) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall network::set_up_pattern(int)" (?set_up_pattern@network@@QAEXH@Z) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall network::forward_prop(void)" (?forward_prop@network@@QAEXXZ) already defined in kohonen.obj
layerk.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall network::backward_prop(float &)" (?backward_prop@network@@QAEXAAM@Z) already defined in kohonen.obj
Debug/Test4.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

The code source of the program can be downloaded here
http://blog.drsofts.com/konohen.zip

Comment: You should reformulate your question. In this form it will be likely closed. No one is going to download and inspect your program. Some cooperation **is** required.

Comment: Looks like you are either linking the same object file twice, or define same functions twice by way of messing #includes or such. Try linking with verbose output and gaining more info from it. Try taking out kohonen.cpp out of the projects. Then explain what you tried and what the results were.

Answer (score 4):

Without looking at you code, only at the errors, it seems you have done one of the following:

1. implemented some functions in the header but outside a class definition without marking the functions inline
2. implemented functions multiply in different object files
3. included a .cpp file instead of a header file

I'd personally guess the third is the case: check kohonen.cpp  and layerk.cpp for this problem. It may also be in one of the headers included from these files. You can use the -E or /E compiler option to get the result of preprocessing a file: this may help finding where the function definitions cone from.